# Firebase messed up Google Play Games Service authentication and saved data

Tags: unity, google-play, google-play-services, firebase

Currently, I'm collaborating on advertising my game with Google's official advertising team.

Recently, they requested me to link my game with Firebase to track user events and analysis. So I made a new Firebase project and entered SHA-1 digital fingerprint on that project today.

But after doing this, all users can't able to authenticate to Google Play Services anymore. So I removed the SHA-1 back from the Firebase project, and it seems to work back, but it lost all the saved progress in SavedGames.

Countless users will keep losing their data causing this. It's a desperate situation. Can anyone help me?

Unity version: 2019.4.3f1
Google Play Games Plugin for Unity version: 0.10.12

Comment: Are you still linked against the new database or you fully switched back to the old one? How do you identify a user from your against your data base user save data?

Comment: @Zibelas There's no such database. I'm using GPGS SavedGames feature for saving their data. Is this related to this issue?

Comment: It depends on your implementation I would say. SavedGames needs to have an identifier for each user (usually their google id or similar). And something that tells what is your game. All you wrote in the question is that you added a new Firebase, the Sha didnt work on that and you removed it again. But did you revert to the old Firebase (that might or might not be used as part of your SavedGames identifier?)

Comment: @Zibelas Nope, I never reverted to some kind of old firebase kind of thing. I just removed SHA-1 fingerprints, and that's it. Nothing after done. And my implementation is just simple, I just signed in to GPGS by using "PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate()", and load data from Saved Games using "SavedGameClient.ReadBinaryData()". There's no such kind of specifying the user id, it just loads data from the currently active user.

Comment: `To use the plugin, you must first configure your game in the Google Play Developer Console. Follow the instructions on creating a client ID. Be particularly careful when entering your package name and your certificate fingerprints, since mistakes on those screens can be difficult to recover from.` as per the readme from https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/README.md Did you delete that one as well?

Comment: @Zibelas GPGS plugin has been working for the last 2 years without any problem. I added the Firebase Analytics plugin in the last update, about 4 days ago to track user data and events. There were no additional steps to follow in the instruction, so  I thought that it was done.

But still, FB Analytics didn't work and today I found the tutorial video and figured out that I have to add SHA-1 to my FB project too. And this is the beginning of this whole disaster, everything just suddenly goes nuts after I added. It's not going back even though I deleted it back.